# Android - relative bitmap size in the layer-list

Tags: android, xamarin, android-bitmap, layer-list

I am trying to make a splash screen for Android app in Xamarin. I have created xml file in the drawable folder, which is used as a background in a theme and presented using custom Activity.

I have done that successfully. Image is fixed size and it is centered in the middle of the view. Works great for portrait and landscape mode.

This is the code of the splash_screen.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <color android:color="@color/launcher_background"/>
  </item>
  <item
    android:height="500px"
    android:width="500px"
    android:gravity="center">
    <bitmap
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_rounded"/>
        android:gravity="fill"/>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

And this is a theme:

```
<style name="SplashTheme">
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>  
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

What I want to achieve, is to make image relative to the screen size, so width and height to be 60% of the width in the portrait mode, and 60% of the height in the landscape mode.

Is this doable, and how?

Comment: Could you please post the full code of the  `splash_screen`? There are some problem with your code.

Comment: It is full code, but color tag wasn't formatted properly. It is correct now. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use two images with different size to switch when the screen alternate between portrait mode and  landscape mode.Because changing the height or width will effect  the image display effect.

Meanwhile, we can set the root layout a background with the layer-list instead of using it as a background in a theme.

So you can do like this:

activitylayout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/splash_screen"
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<!--   other code  -->
</LinearLayout>
```

splash_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item android:drawable="@color/gray_dark"/>

 <item
android:id="@+id/layer_photo"
android:height="500dp"
android:width="500dp"
android:drawable="@drawable/agirl"
android:gravity="center">
</item>
```

CurrentActivity.cs

```
LinearLayout root_layout;

root_layout = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.root_layout);
```

function `OnConfigurationChanged`

```
      public override void OnConfigurationChanged(Android.Content.Res.Configuration newConfig)
    {
        base.OnConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable)this.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.splash_screen);
        if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Portrait)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Portrait...");
            Drawable drawable = this.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.agirl);
            layerDrawable.SetDrawableByLayerId(Resource.Id.layer_photo, drawable);

            root_layout.SetBackgroundDrawable(layerDrawable);              
        }
        else if (newConfig.Orientation == Android.Content.Res.Orientation.Landscape)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Landscape...");
            Drawable drawable = this.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.img123);
            layerDrawable.SetDrawableByLayerId(Resource.Id.layer_photo, drawable);

            root_layout.SetBackgroundDrawable(layerDrawable);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Image size, depends of the screen resolution, and it is the same for portrait and landscape. Image width and height are the same and it should be 60% of the width in the portrait mode and 60% of the height in the landscape mode (portrait.width == landscape.height).

Comment: Sorry so late to reply, have you resolved your question?

Comment: No. If you have more ideas I am eager to hear. Thx